# ASPNET.Core SignalR authenticates inconsistently between clients

Tags: c#, angular, wpf, .net-5, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using ASPNet Core SignalR on .NET 5. Authorization works from both WPF and Angular as long as I have the [Authorize] attribute on the hub itself. However, when I place the [Authorize] on a method in the hub, it fails to authorize that method on my Angular client. It succeeds for the WPF client.

The server hub is pretty a standard Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub.

```
   // [Authorize]   This works for both WPF and Angular
     public class MyHub: Hub
        {
            [Authorize]   // This only works for WPF. For Angular it fails
            async Task<string> SubscribeAuthorize()
            {
                ... stuff
            }
            async Task<string> SubscribeUnauthorized()
            {
                ... stuff
            }
        }
```

When I look at the server logs during the Angular failure case I see:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: Successfully validated the token.
```

Followed shortly after by...

```
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

When I compare the logs for the WPF (version and the web version, there seem to be some protocol differences)

// WPF Success

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:44307/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: Successfully validated the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint '/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint '/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:44307/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0 - 200 316 application/json 7.7400ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44307/WorkspaceEditHub?id=x4aYtUdkDXIHTcwXLuictw - -
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: Successfully validated the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint '/WorkspaceEditHub'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful.
```

// Angular failure

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2 OPTIONS https://localhost:44307/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate - -
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService: Information: CORS policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/2 OPTIONS https://localhost:44307/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate - - - 204 - - 6.7752ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44307/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService: Information: CORS policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: Successfully validated the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint '/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint '/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44307/WorkspaceEditHub/negotiate text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0 - 200 273 application/json 38.9649ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44307/WorkspaceEditHub?id=
<long bunch of stuff that isn't in the WPF log> - -
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService: Information: CORS policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint '/WorkspaceEditHub'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint '/WorkspaceEditHub'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44307/WorkspaceEditHub?id=<long bunch of stuff that isn't in the WPF log> - - - 101 - - 99.6336ms
```

Finally, here is how I am setting up the hub in WPF (this works)

```
var proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
SignalRHub = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(url, options =>
{
    options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(_credentials.Token);
    options.Proxy=proxy;
}).Build();
await SignalRHub.StartAsync();
string jsonResult=await SignalRHub.InvokeAsync<string>("SubscribeAuthorize");
```

And here is how I am setting it up in Angular (which fails)

```
  const options: IHttpConnectionOptions = {
      accessTokenFactory: () => {
        return this.oidcSecurityService.getToken();
      }
    };
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(url, options).build();
    await this.hubConnection.start();
    let result = await this.hubConnection.invoke("SubscribeAuthorize");
```

It feels like I am really close since as mentioned earlier [Authorize] does work with exactly the same client code if it's at the Hub level instead of the method level.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution. Like much server stuff the solution seems more like spell ingredients than actual code.

It turns out SignalR needed a help getting at the token. Not sure why it was able to find the token when [Authorize] was at the hub level and not find it at the method level, or why WPF worked, but clearly the Angular client is setting up the request slightly differently.

In Startup.cs under ConfigureServices

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
    // other options...

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
        
        // If the request is for our hub...
        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
             (path.StartsWithSegments("/hub")))   // Your hub path here
        {
             // Read the token out of the query string
             context.Token = accessToken;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```